# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR to SUBSTR + INSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I am trying to convert the following code from oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (code,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL),2,8),']','') code
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (code, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Please assist to convert it into some SUBSTR / INSTR combination or CASE function.

Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: Do you understand what this snippet does? Are you saying you want the same behaviour but with the use of regex? What are you expecting to replace it with? Have you got an example of the contents of the string `code`?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code is intended to do.  Also, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, as the `DUAL` table does not have a `code` column; however, if we assume that you are using a different table which does have that column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( code ) AS
SELECT '[1],[22],[333],[4444],[55555],[666666],[7777777],[88888888],[999999999],[0000000000]' FROM DUAL
```

Then you can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( code, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT code,
         1,
         INSTR( code, ',', 1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT code,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( code, ',', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       REPLACE(
         CASE end_pos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR( code, start_pos + 1, 8 )
         ELSE SUBSTR( code, start_pos + 1, LEAST( end_pos - start_pos - 1, 8 ) )
         END,
         ']'
       ) AS code
FROM   rsqfc;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | CODE     |
> | :------- |
> | 99999999 |
> | 4444     |
> | 55555    |
> | 1        |
> | 333      |
> | 22       |
> | 666666   |
> | 88888888 |
> | 00000000 |
> | 7777777  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63e37f8114ef0c64d44fb6412ffb6c88)*

Comment: Thank you so much dear :-) Let me try this. will get back in case of any issue.

Comment: One more question, I have a procedure where i have a cursor actually like below:

Comment: @ImranQasim If it is a different question then ask it as a new question; don't add it as a comment to another question.