# oracle Regular expression conversion to substr/instr & case function

Tags: sql, oracle

Kindly help me in conversion of the following with `substr` / `instr` & case function to keep it simple:

```sql
SELECT ROWNUM serlnumb,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (in_mail, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) emailadd
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (in_mail, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Using INSTR and SUBSTR does not make this "simple". It does require that you understand regular expressions, which is something you may need to learn. I suggest [this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is practically a [duplicate of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66720075/1509264) but without using `DISTINCT` and `SUBSTR` on the output.

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( mail, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT in_mail,
         1,
         INSTR( in_mail, ',', 1 )
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT mail,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( mail, ',', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( mail, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR( mail, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END AS emailadd
FROM   rsqfc;
```

Which, if `in_mail` is a (bind or PL/SQL) variable with the value `abc,def,ghi` gives the output:

> ```
> | EMAILADD |
> | :------- |
> | abc      |
> | def      |
> | ghi      |
> ```

However, if you are using that in PL/SQL then it will involve a context switch from the PL/SQL scope to SQL. You may be better to [write a PL/SQL function to split the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577315/1509264):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Then you can use it directly in PL/SQL without having to switch contexts to SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  in_mail VARCHAR2(20) := 'abc,def,ghi';
  v_emailadds SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  v_emailadds := SPLIT_STRING( in_mail );
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_emailadds.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_emailadds(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> abc
> def
> ghi
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2d3d72925c921bb8749038e57c19097e)*

Comment: Thanks a lot dear... actually I am not a developer, trying to understand how to convert such codes to simple substr etc... the previous code was different with 1,8 value. However, Thanks a lot for the assistance.